# Problem with mTLS configuration of Custom domain names configuration of AWS API Gateway using S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm unable to configure mTLS in "Custom domain names" option of AWS API Gateway.

Below are steps I have followed to configure mutual TLS configuration: I have a root account and its child account.

**Root Account Steps:**

- Created a new client certificate using "client certificates" option of API gateway in root account.
- Downloaded the new certificate. the new certificate file name is `qde1ca.cert`. Renamed the `qde1ca.cert` file using `mv qde1ca.cert gateway.truststore.pem.
- Uploaded `gateway.truststore.pem` file to a directory application-truststore of S3 bucket of Root Account. The S3 bucket name is integrations-us-east-1. The directory has version enabled. So, my S3 file path is `s3://integrations-us-east-1/application-truststore/gateway.truststore.pem`
  Noted Object URI and Version ID of the newly uploaded gateway.truststore.pem file.

**Child Account Steps**

In child account, I tried to configure mutual TLS of Custom domain name of API Gateway.

- enabled Mutual TLS authentication option
- Configure Truststore URI as the Object URI (s3://integrations-us-east-1/application-truststore/gateway.truststore.pem)
- Truststore version as Version ID of the newly uploaded gateway.truststore.pem file.
  Saved this configuration.

**When I test using Frontend that invoke APIs of API gateway, it seems that the APIs are not executing. However, when I reset the mutual TLS configuration using OLD values Object URI and Version ID, The APIs in API Gateway works correctly!!!**

What am I missing into the new mutual TLS configuration of Custom domain names configuration of API Gateway?